# CPXRegisterLicense was not declared in this scope in CPLEX v12.7

Tags: cplex

Till CPLEX 12.6 this method was there. Looks like in 12.7 this is missing. Do anyone knows about the alternate method to use in C++ for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method is depricated in CPLEX 12.6.2 version. More details are below.

[IBM ILOG](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=9883f0f9-75b2-49ce-bb3a-38b9cc037015&ps=100#repliesPg=0)